# ROR + Reopen a new tab in same window using RUBY code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my project, I want to `re-open a new tab using ruby code`. When user clicks at attachment link, then that pdf should be open in new tab of same window. I tried a lot but I am not getting the way to solve it. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is possible using Ruby since it deals with the UI part. It is indeed very much possible using HTML and Jquery.

You could simply set the `target` attribute as blank in the hyperlink redirecting to the PDF and it will open the file in a new tab. Something similar to this :

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/files/xyz.pdf" target="_blank">
```

If you want to use JQuery for this, you can try something like this :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
   link_host = this.href.split("/")[2];
   document_host = document.location.href.split("/")[2];

   if (link_host != document_host) {
     window.open(this.href);
     return false;
    }
  });
});
```